# if $(f_n)$ is $\mathcal C^1(]a,b[)$ and converge to $f$, then $f$ is Lipschitz.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a sequence of function $\mathcal C^1(]a,b[)$ such that $(f_n')_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded. We suppose that $f_n$ converge uniformly to $f$. Show that $f$ is Lipschitz.

I really have difficulties to solve this problem. I don't see in what the that $f_n$ are $\mathcal C^1(]a,b[)$ can help.

Comment: I believe the assumption that the sequence of derivatives of the $f_n$ is bounded is the important thing here and you need the $f_n$ to be in $C^1(]a,b[)$ to talk about derivatives in the first place.

Comment: Moreover, It tells you that the derivatives are continuous

Comment: @Surb: Sorry, I corrected it, you right, the convergence is uniform.

Comment: Hint: Show that this sequence is uniformly Lipschitz. Thus will imply uniformly convergence etc.

Comment: Is uniform convergence necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some ideas. Let $x,y \in ]a,b[$. Since $f_n \to f$ uniformly (I believe pointwise is enough though) we have
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x), \ \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(y) = f(y)$$
and in particular
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| = |f(x) - f(y)|$$
Since each $f_n$ is $C^1 (]a,b[)$ and $x,y \in ]a,b[$ and we know that $\{ f_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence whose terms are bounded above by some $M > 0$ then we can show (hint : use the mean value theorem appropriately) that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$ |f_n (x) - f_n(y)| \leq M |x - y|$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: In fact, looking your proof, maybe it also work with pointwise convergence only... interesting, I thought it wasn't...

Comment: Yes, I just commented on the main post as well. In particular the second line can be proven for pointwise convergence since
$$ ||f_n(x) - f_n(y)| - |f(x) - f(y)|| \leq |f_n (x) - f(x) - (f_n(y) - f(y))| \leq |f_n (x) - f(x)| + |f_n(y) - f(y)|$$